# Why I cannot set the color of the pseudo class element to red?

Tags: css, less

Here is my test code: http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/n41zm2s7/4/

HTML:

```
<div class='test'>
    <div class="icon icon-test">Testing</div>
</div>
```

Less:

```
.icon-test {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    speak: None;
}

.icon-test:before {
        content:"-";
}

.test {
    .icon {
        color:red;
    } 

}
```

Which is compiled to

```
.icon-test {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  speak: None;
}
.icon-test:before {
  content: "-";
}
.test .icon {
  color: red;
}
```

I am expecting to change the color of the character '-' to red. What is wrong with these code?

Comment: just use `.icon-test:before {
        content:"-";
    color:red;
}`

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't support LESS (which you have misidentified in your question as CSS despite having [less] in your tags). That is why. It should work normally.

Comment: jsFiddle supports SCSS, but it must be enabled in "Languages": http://jsfiddle.net/n41zm2s7/3/

Comment: @Oriol Thanks for the tip! So SCSS is another name for `Less`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I think they are not exactly the same, but they share some syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your content inside the CSS panel is invalid. Next, if you want to change the color of the pseudo element only then add the `color` property to the `.icon-test:before` rule instead.

```css
.icon-test {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  speak: None;
}
.icon-test:before {
  content: "-";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div class="icon icon-test">Testing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It changes all the text to color red. I just want the '-' to change